# primefaces data table not updating after filtering in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, primefaces, jsf-2

I am using primefaces 5.x, IE 11 browser

After filtering call the data table is not updating for one column, but for other columns it's working.

Here is my xhtml code

```
   <div>
        <p:commandButton id="filterButton" value="#{msgs.quality_incident_filter_button}" icon="ui-icon-search"  actionListener="#{bean.doFilter()}"
                    styleClass="green_button" " process="@form"/>



         <p:dataTable id="gd" " value="#{bean.lazyDataModel}" lazy="true" var="p" rowKey="#{p.id}" selectionMode="single"
                  liveResize="true"
                filterDelay="600" paginator="true" rows="20" paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                currentPageReportTemplate="({currentPage} #{msgs.of} {totalPages})" styleClass="pst-grid" rowStyleClass="#{pst.leadPst ?  'lead_pst_row' : ''}">

          --other columns

          --column for which if filter applied not working 
           <p:column headerText="${msgs.pst_materials}" id="m" field="materials" exportable="true"
                    filterBy="" filterStyleClass="hidefilter" sortBy="#{p.materials}">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText styleClass="ui-column-title-block" value="${msgs.pst_materials}" />
                    </f:facet>                      
                    <f:facet name="filter">
                        <p:inputMask value="#{bean.filter.material}" styleClass="ui-column-inputfield"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <ui:repeat var="mat" value="#{p.availableMaterials}" exportSeparator="\r\n">                                    
                        <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{lbean.formatMaterialNumber(mat.mdMaterial.materialNumber)}" /><br/>
                        <p:tooltip for="outputText">
                            <ui:repeat var="mater" value="#{p.availableMaterials}" exportSeparator="\r\n">                                  
                                <h:outputText id="outputText" value="#{mater.mdMaterial.label}" /><br/>
                            </ui:repeat>
                        </p:tooltip>
                    </ui:repeat>
                </p:column>

    </datatable>
  </div>
```

For every other column if I apply filter it's working in IE, chrome
 only for this column if I apply filter not working

backing bean filter method working correctly, it's giving correct results only data table is not updated.

Please help me

Comment: I can find any documentation for exportSeparator on ui:repeat. Where is the documentation of this?